# Simplifying Activities with Results

Tags: java, android

I have an implementation for making calling out to other activities easier, and I just wanted to get some input on it for potential pitfalls.  It kind of goes against the way that Android is designed, but it makes building linkages between activities SO much nicer.  Essentially, Android wants all linkages between activities to be dealt with statically, so that Android can restart activities whenever it wants, and the savedInstanceState stuff will make sure everything picks up where it left off.  However, this prevents some dynamicism that would make activity-activity interactions much easier, and localize the code for a specific function (personally, I hate having code for one thing have to live in multiple places).

Anyway, here is my code.  This lives in the base class for all of the application's activities.

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity {
    // keeping track of unique request codes 
    int lastRequestCode = 10000;

    // List of callbacks
    private Map<Integer, ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>> registeredActivityResultCallbacks = new HashMap<>();

    // Helper function to allow starting activities and registering
    // callbacks dynamically
    public void startActivityForDynamicResult(Intent i, ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> cb) {
        int requestCode = lastRequestCode++;
        registeredActivityResultCallbacks.put(requestCode, cb);
        startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
    }

    // When an app returns to this activity, look for the relevant callback to call
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Dynamically-registered callbacks
        ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> cb = registeredActivityResultCallbacks.get(requestCode);
        if(cb != null) {
            ActivityResult result = new ActivityResult(resultCode, data);
            cb.onActivityResult(result);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows subclasses to do things like this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppActivity {
    public void someAction() {
        startActivityForDynamicResult(new Intent(this, SomeOtherActivity.class), result -> {
            if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                String value = result.getData().getStringExtra("Something");
                // do something
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The advantage is that this completely localizes what you are trying to accomplish, which makes code easier to read, write, and maintain long-term.  The problem is that it at least somewhat goes against Android dev principles because if Android kills the app, it is no longer possible to restore this dynamically-created linkage.

How much of a problem is this paradigm?  Is there a way to get around Android's limitations in this manner?  Or other manner of mitigation?

For my present app, it is pretty much guaranteed to be running foreground on the device (so Android won't be killing any of its activities), but I'm more curious as to the wider applicability of this pattern.

Comment: Violation of activity lifecycle is enough issue to not consider this. Turn on "don't keep activities" in developer settings (which simulates a device running out of memory) and see your solution crumble.

Comment: @Pawel - any thoughts for a better solution?

Comment: FWIW, modern Android app development leans away from having multiple activities, preferring multiple fragments or composables in one (or a few) activities.